# How do I go about creating vector maps from GPS data, deploying it on a server, and then navigating on it from a mobile device?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, gps, gis

We considered using Google Maps API for our purpose, but it does not have a way to add custom roadblocks. Since our delivery is time-bound, we can't have our shipments face closed gates, roadblocks, and so on. An ideal solution would have been to tell Google to avoid certain routes if they pass through such points - but there is no way to do this, as yet.

Interestingly, this is [an acknowledged issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=214) from Google.

The next best solution for our logistics vertical is to go full-blown on the thing: use GPS data (images, longitudes and latitudes) and create a vector map, host it on a server, and have a device navigate on this freshly-created maps.

How would one go about this? What are the resources and tools required to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds interesting but you need a lot of research and hard. Try to research how `Waze` does the same thing. Also OSM seems the right choice.